# How to create a new key in a list of dictionaries that is a sum of another key?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary like this:

```py
[
    {'name': 'a', 'age': '20', 'value': '10'},
    {'name': 'a', 'age': '30', 'value': '15'},
    {'name': 'a', 'age': '40', 'value': '25'},
    {'name': 'b', 'age': '20', 'value': '11'},
    {'name': 'b', 'age': '30', 'value': '12'},
    {'name': 'b', 'age': '40', 'value': '13'}
]
```

Now I want to add a new key with the sum of all values for the same name, like so:

```py
[
    {'name': 'a', 'age': '20', 'value': '10', 'sum': '50'},
    {'name': 'a', 'age': '30', 'value': '15', 'sum': '50'},
    {'name': 'a', 'age': '40', 'value': '25', 'sum': '50'},
    {'name': 'b', 'age': '20', 'value': '11', 'sum': '36'},
    {'name': 'b', 'age': '30', 'value': '12', 'sum': '36'},
    {'name': 'b', 'age': '40', 'value': '13', 'sum': '36'}
]
```

I am already using Pandas for grouping and aggregating. Is this possible with Pandas as well or is there standard Python variant?

Comment: Have you tried solving this issue ? If so can you provide the code ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no clue how to do it. I only used Pandas to aggregate an even larger list of dicts to this and now I want to add the sum as described

Comment: ChatGPT should be able to deal with most Pandas homework problems. There isn't any need to post it on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

To create a new key in a list of dictionaries that is a sum of another key, you can iterate through each dictionary in the list and calculate the sum of the desired keys. Then, add a new key with the calculated sum to each dictionary. Here's a Python example assuming you want to add a new key called 'sum_key' that contains the sum of 'key1' and 'key2':

```py
# Example list of dictionaries
list_of_dicts = [
    {'key1': 10, 'key2': 20},
    {'key1': 5, 'key2': 15},
    {'key1': 8, 'key2': 12}
]

# Iterate through the list and calculate the sum of 'key1' and 'key2'
for dictionary in list_of_dicts:
    dictionary['sum_key'] = dictionary['key1'] + dictionary['key2']

# Resulting list of dictionaries with the new 'sum_key' added
print(list_of_dicts)
```

The output will be:

```
[
    {'key1': 10, 'key2': 20, 'sum_key': 30},
    {'key1': 5, 'key2': 15, 'sum_key': 20},
    {'key1': 8, 'key2': 12, 'sum_key': 20}
]
```

Now each dictionary in the list has a new key 'sum_key' containing the sum of 'key1' and 'key2'.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, without [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas), using pure Python:

```py
lst = [
    {"name": "a", "age": "20", "value": "10"},
    {"name": "a", "age": "30", "value": "15"},
    {"name": "a", "age": "40", "value": "25"},
    {"name": "b", "age": "20", "value": "11"},
    {"name": "b", "age": "30", "value": "12"},
    {"name": "b", "age": "40", "value": "13"},
]

out = {}
for d in lst:
    out.setdefault(d["name"], []).append(d)

tmp = {k: sum(int(i["value"]) for i in v) for k, v in out.items()}

out = [{**v, "sum": str(tmp[v["name"]])} for v in lst]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[
    {"name": "a", "age": "20", "value": "10", "sum": "50"},
    {"name": "a", "age": "30", "value": "15", "sum": "50"},
    {"name": "a", "age": "40", "value": "25", "sum": "50"},
    {"name": "b", "age": "20", "value": "11", "sum": "36"},
    {"name": "b", "age": "30", "value": "12", "sum": "36"},
    {"name": "b", "age": "40", "value": "13", "sum": "36"},
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option without pandas but with a defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [{'name': 'a', 'age': '20', 'value': '10'},
        {'name': 'a', 'age': '30', 'value': '15'},
        {'name': 'a', 'age': '40', 'value': '25'},
        {'name': 'b', 'age': '20', 'value': '11'},
        {'name': 'b', 'age': '30', 'value': '12'},
        {'name': 'b', 'age': '40', 'value': '13'}]

temp = defaultdict(int)

for d in data:
    temp[d['name']] += int(d['value'])

for d in data:
    d['sum'] = str(temp[d['name']])

print(data)
```

...or without a defaultdict...

```
temp = {}

for d in data:
    name = d['name']
    temp[name] = temp.get(name, 0) + int(d['value'])

for d in data:
    d['sum'] = str(temp[d['name']])
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code updates each dictionary in the list with a new "sum" key, which is the sum of values from each dictionary with the same "name" key.

```
your_list = [
    {'name': 'a', 'age': '20', 'value': '10'}, 
    {'name': 'a', 'age': '30', 'value': '15'},
    {'name': 'a', 'age': '40', 'value': '25'},  
    {'name': 'b', 'age': '20', 'value': '11'}, 
    {'name': 'b', 'age': '30', 'value': '12'},
    {'name': 'b', 'age': '40', 'value': '13'},
    ...
]

previous = {}
for obj in your_list:
    name = obj["name"]
    
    # Check if we already calculated the sum
    value_sum = previous.get(name)
    if value_sum is None:
        value_sum = sum(int(d["value"]) for d in your_list if d["name"] == name)
        previous[name] = value_sum
    
    obj["sum"] = str(value_str)  # If you want it as type 'str'

print(your_list)
```

Output:

```
>>>
{'name': 'a', 'age': '20', 'value': '10', 'sum': '50'}
{'name': 'a', 'age': '30', 'value': '15', 'sum': '50'}
{'name': 'a', 'age': '40', 'value': '25', 'sum': '50'}
{'name': 'b', 'age': '20', 'value': '11', 'sum': '36'}
{'name': 'b', 'age': '30', 'value': '12', 'sum': '36'}
{'name': 'b', 'age': '40', 'value': '13', 'sum': '36'}
...
```

Answer (score -1):

This will do the job:

```
list_of_dicts = [
    {'key1': 10, 'key2': 20},
    {'key1': 5, 'key2': 15},
    {'key1': 8, 'key2': 12}]

for idx in range(len(list_of_dicts)):
    list_of_dicts[idx].update({'sum_keys': sum(list_of_dicts[idx].values())})
```

[image: Output]